# Analytic function f constant if $f(z) = 0$ or $f'(z) = 0$ for all $z$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be analytic and suppose that for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, at least one of $f(z)$ and $f'(z)$ is equal to 0. Proof that $f$ is constant.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: In your title you mention $f''$, but in your body $f'$. Which do you mean?

Comment: $f'$ thanks, fixed it.

Comment: We have that $f(z) f'(z) = 0$ So if $f(z)$ is not $0$ then $f'(z) = 0$ However this implies the value does not change in the neighbourhood of $f(z)$. If almost every point is an extremum then $f$ cannot be analytic and unbounded at the same time. Hence $f$ is constant. That is not formal , its just a comment. Notice an entire function only has at most a countable amount of zero's or it is identical to $0$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint: 
$$
(?)'(z)=f(z)f'(z)=0\qquad\forall z.
$$

Comment: Hehe...+1 for that teasing yet nice (?) there.

Comment: @julien I may be missing something, but don't you mean $((?)(z))'$ and of course $(?)'(z)$ also works for an appropiate $?$, but if I got it right it $((?)(z))'$ should be clearer.

Comment: @GitGud does not matter since $dz = 1$.

Comment: In case the OP is confused , Integrate ...

Comment: @GitGud I was thinking $(?)=g$ with $g=f^2/2$.  I added the parenthesis because I wanted the $'$ to be more apparent than in $?'$.

Comment: @julien Ok. Nice answer as always anyway.

Comment: @GitGud Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GitGud: There aren't many contexts where $(g(z))'$ is meaningful. One would be for instance where $g:\mathbf C\to\mathcal C^1(\mathbf R)$, a map whose values are differentiable functions (and the value $(g(z))'$ would be the unevaluated derivative function of the image $g(z)$ of $z$). It is not likely that is useful here.

Answer (score 5):

Alternative ... since $\{z:f(z)=0\}$ and $\{z:f'(z)=0\}$ are both closed sets, if their union is the whole plane then at least one of them has nonempty interior.

**addition**
The same method works for a countable union by the Baire category theorem.  So:

Let $f$ be an entire function, and suppose for each $z \in \mathbb C$ at least one of $f(z), f'(z), f''(z), f'''(z),\cdots$ is zero.  Then $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: Despite my answer, I like it when one uses a more involved theorem like Baire to solve such a question. Thanks for sharing, +1. And that's a very nice generalization.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the comments:

Since one of $f$ and $f'$ is zero everywhere,
for all $z$,
$0 = f(z)f'(z) = (1/2)(f(z)^2)'$,
so $f(z)^2$ is constant,
so $f(z)$ is constant.